# Predicting over data that has categorical, numerical and text

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build a classifier for my dataset. Each observation in the data has categorical and numerical values, as well as a more general description in free-text. I understand how to build a boosting algorithm to handle the categorical and numerical values, and I have already trained a neural network that predicted over the text quite succesfully. What I'm wrapping my head around is how to integrate both approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Embed your free text using a Language Model (e.g. averaging `fasttext` wordembeddings, or using `google-universal-sentence-encoder`) into an N-dim vector of floats. One hot encode the categorical stuff. Concatenate [embedding, one_hot_encoding, numericals] and badabing badaboom, you've got yourself 1 vector representing your datapoint.

Tensorflow hub's `KerasLayer` + https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4 is def a good starting point. I you need to train something yourself, you could look into `tf.keras.layers.Embedding`.